# Difference between Server-side and Backend

Tags: javascript, backend, server-side

What is the difference between Server-side and Backend?

I am new to all of this coding and I want to create a website. I'm going to use Node.js for the backend, but what is server-side? Can someone explain in simple words to me how this works? Also, what is a backend anyway?

Comment: Those terms mean the same thing.

Comment: For a website you will be creating, it is implicit that it will hosted somewhere and a user will use a browser to interact with it. The division is browser (aka client-side) vs hosted (aka server-side). Node.js is a framework that will run on the server (not on the browser), hence can be referred to server-side. Backend, can mean Node.js in your case, or if the Node.js application interacts with a database or other services, those all collectively be called, backend.

Comment: If you want to make a website, I'd recommend starting with learning HTML, CSS, and JS, and creating a frontend first.

Comment: @SLaks I don't think it's entirely true from my perspective, frontend can be on server-side (i.e. Rails/.NET Views, React Server-Rendering). I see client/server side as physical division and backend/frontend as a logical division.

Comment: 1) Contrary to what many people say, they are not exactly the same, especially when it comes to web development. The server-side includes some parts of the front-end. For example, you can build a simple website that doesn't have back-end codes nor database, but you can't say there is no server-side. [(check the top answer at here)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-server-side-and-back-end)
2) These terms come up very often in programming and are very important for beginners to understand, but it is funny that they are "off-topic" :)

Comment: In the context of web development(since the term "backend" is usually used in web development), we can think there are "web browser", "frontend server", "backend server", and "database". A web browser is a client; the rest are server-side; "frontend server" hosts static resources such as HTML, CSS, and javascript code, and a "static web hosting service" does that for you, if you want; "backend server" and "database" are the ones people usually call "backend" - "web browser(client)" or "frontend server" communicate with "backend server" with some APIs (to be continued...)

Comment: (...continued) and "backend server" communicates with "database". "Static webpage" needs only a "frontend server", no need for "backend" part. In "Dynamic webpage", if CSR(Client Side Rendering) is used, in many cases the web browser downloads the static resources(HTML, CSS, js) from the "frontend server" at the beginning, and then the web browser talks with the "backend server" with API. If SSR(Server Side Rendering) is used, the web browser gets the static resources from the "frontend server", which talks with the "backend server", which in turn talks with "database".

Comment: Normally "frontend server" is called a "web server" and the "backend server" is called a "web application server". FYI, in many cases, SPA(Single Page Application) involves CSR.

Answer (score 5):

Server-side and Back-end are identical statements. They both mean that the code is run on you server as opposed to the clients machine, often for dealing with databases. Where as Client-side and Front-end both mean the code is executed on the users computer, usually for UI and design.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side

Answer (score 1):

The back-end, or the "server-side", is basically how the site works, updates and changes. This refers to everything the user can't see in the browser, like databases and servers.

Node is your "server-side" in this case.

The front-end is everything involved with what the user sees, including design.

You can read more [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/whats-difference-front-end-back-end)

Answer (score 1):

**Backend** defines a component in a logical separation of an application.
This component is running **server-side**. The backend is responsible for handling data, authentication, database access etc.

The **Frontend** is another component which is running **client-side**. Its what the user sees and interacts with. It sends data to the backend where it is stored in databases.